# How to connect node's amqplib with ssl connection?

Tags: node.js, ssl, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm tryting to connect my RabbitMQ server, which is forced to use SSL, and protected with user and password. Previously, I succeeded to connected to this server from C#, PHP and Python applications.

This is my node.js code:

```
const amqp = require('amqplib');
const fs = require('fs');

const config = {...}

const opts = {
    ca: [fs.readFileSync(config.certificatePath)]
};

const url = `amqps://${config.username}:${config.password}@${config.hostname}:${config.port}`;

const open = amqp.connect(url, opts);

open.then(function(conn) {
    console.log('connected.');
}).then(null, console.warn);
```

The error I get is: unable to get local issuer certificate

1) What does the error mean?

2) What do I need to do in order to connect?

Note: In the [library's ssl guide](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/ssl.html) it is written "(must) supply an options object which will be passed through to `tls.connect()`."
I could not understand this directive, nor do they have an example of `tls.connect()` use. I tried some variations but failed, maybe it will give a clue to someone here.

Comment: In your case `config.certificatePath` this is the certificate file being used by the server?

Comment: Actually I tried it both ways. One try with the same certificate, the other try, with different certificates.

Answer (score 3):

I gave it a try with `amqplib` version `0.5.3`, and here is my working example, `src/amqplib-ssl-example.js`:

```
var fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

var opts = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../ssl/client/client_certificate.pem')),
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../ssl/client/private_key.pem')),
  ca: [fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../ssl/testca/ca_certificate_bundle.pem'))],
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}

var q = 'tasks'

function bail (err) {
  console.error(err)
  process.exit(1)
}

// Publisher
function publisher (conn) {
  conn.createChannel(onOpen)
  function onOpen (err, ch) {
    if (err != null) bail(err)
    ch.assertQueue(q)
    const msg = 'something to do'
    ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from(msg))
    console.log('Publisher: ', msg)
  }
}

// Consumer
function consumer (conn) {
  conn.createChannel(onOpen)
  function onOpen (err, ch) {
    if (err != null) bail(err)
    ch.assertQueue(q)
    ch.consume(q, function (msg) {
      if (msg !== null) {
        console.log('Consumer: ', msg.content.toString())
        ch.ack(msg)
      }
    })
  }
}

require('amqplib/callback_api')
  .connect('amqps://guest:guest@localhost', opts, function (err, conn) {
    if (err != null) bail(err)
    consumer(conn)
    publisher(conn)
  })
```

When you run this code, `node src/amqplib-ssl-example.js`, this is the output:

```
Publisher:  something to do
Consumer:  something to do
```

And the RabbitMQ server logs the following message, where you can see that the connection is via SSL.

```
rabbitmq_1  | 2019-03-24 00:05:41.579 [info] <0.431.0> started TLS (SSL) listener on [::]:5671
...
rabbitmq_1  | 2019-03-24 00:23:35.938 [info] <0.518.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.518.0> (192.168.96.1:45014 -> 192.168.96.2:5671)
rabbitmq_1  | 2019-03-24 00:23:35.949 [info] <0.518.0> connection <0.518.0> (192.168.96.1:45014 -> 192.168.96.2:5671): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
```

And for your information, I manually generate the certificate for this example's purpose, following the instruction below:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#manual-certificate-generation

Answer (score 0):

You have your certificate path assigned to the `ca`, you're missing your `cert` and `key`.

```
var opts = {
  cert: certificateAsBuffer,      // client cert
  key: privateKeyAsBuffer,        // client key
  passphrase: 'MySecretPassword', // passphrase for key
  ca: [caCertAsBuffer]            // array of trusted CA certs
};
```

You can find a reference [here](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/ssl.html)